# Table not displaying data after making an AJAX request

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to retrieve my data from a database using jQuery AJAX. I can't figure out what's wrong in my code. I think i did some mistake in the script section of the code. Any help would be most appreciated

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.userName)
      </th>
      <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.password)
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="AdminList">
    <tr id="loadingStatus" style="color:red">
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
$("#loadingStatus").html("Loading...");
$.get("/Admins/GetAdminData", null, DataBind);

function DataBind(AdminList) {
  var setData = $("#AdminList");
  for (var i = 0; i < AdminList.length; i++) {
    var Data = "<tr class='row_" + AdminList[i].empid + "'>" +
      "<td>" + AdminList[i].username + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + AdminList[i].password + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + "<a href='#' class='btn btn-warning' onclick='EditRecord(" + AdminList[i].empid + ")' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></a>" + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='DeleteRecord(" + AdminList[i].empid + ")'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>" + "</td>" +
      "</tr>";
    SetData.append(Data);
    $("#LoadingStatus").html(" ");
  }
}
```

```csharp
public JsonResult GetAdminData()//needs fixing
{
  List<Admin> ad = new List<Admin>();
  var dat = db.Admins.Select(x => new {
    empid = x.empId,
    username = x.userName,
    passWord = x.password
  }).ToList();

  //foreach(DataRow dr in)
  //{
  //  ad.Add(new Admin
  //  {
  //    userName =
  //  });
  //}

  return Json(dat, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: 'It's not working' isn't really useful information. To start with check the browser console for errors. If there aren't any, set a breakpoint in your server side code and step through it to see exactly what is being returned.

Comment: Also note that `SetData` and `setData` are not the same thing; JS is case-sensitive, like C#

Comment: if i could provide more useful information i would. I'm new to the field so i dont know what to write. i think theres something wrong in my script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

case sensitive issue i changed

```
password = x.password
```